# ASP.NET Core project.json frameworks

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

With **ASP.NET Core** web (and even **.NET Core**) applications, there is a `project.json` file. This JSON files schema is maintained in the [schema-store](http://schemastore.org/json/) where several variations exist. Additionally, this file was detailed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) at one point in time but now suggests it will be updated [here](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/).

Is there a comprehensive breakdown of all the various `frameworks` available, and a corresponding description of what they contain?

Answer (score 2):

You can find them listed on the [NuGet Target Frameworks](https://docs.nuget.org/create/targetframeworks) page, and additional ones for .NET Core on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-standard-applications.md). There are too many to list here, but here are a few related to this question:

**.NET Core**

- netcore
- netcore45
- netcore451
- netcore50

**.NET Framework**

- net451
- net452
- net46
- net461

**DNX**

- dnx
- dnx45
- dnx451
- dnx452

**DNX Core**

- dnxcore
- dnxcore50

You can find some good information on the rest of the `project.json` values [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file). Please keep in mind that it may be a little out of date with the release of RC2.